# Set up CloudWatch email alert with Serverless Framwork for errors, invocations, etc

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework, amazon-sns

I'm trying to set up email alerts for my Lambda errors. I can update my `.yml` file to create a new `topic` and this works OK:

```yaml
custom:
  alerts:
    stages:
      - production
      - dev
      - development
    dashboards: true
    topics:
      alarm:
        topic: ${self:service}-${sls:stage}-alerts-alarm
        notifications:
          - protocol: email
            endpoint: myemail@domain.com
    alarms:
      - functionErrors
      - functionThrottles
      - functionInvocations
      - functionDuration
```

I receive emails as expected.

But when I try to use an existing SNS Topic, by following the SLS [docs](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-aws-alerts#sns-topics), nothing seems to happen. I've:

1. Created a Topic in the SNS console
2. Updated the `.yml` as per the docs:

```yaml
custom:
  alerts:
    stages:
      - production
      - dev
      - development
    topics:
      alarm:
        topic: arn:aws:sns:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:myp-${sls:stage}-alerts
    alarms:
      - functionErrors
      - functionThrottles
      - functionInvocations
      - functionDuration
```

The deploy works fine, but I don't get any emails when I trigger errors. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, though I don't really know what I'm doing differently.

**Successful methodology:**

1. Create a Topic in the SNS console. Click 'Create Topic' after entering the following:

[image]

2. When taken to your new Topic summary screen, click the orange 'Create Subscription' Button. Select 'Email' from the Protocol dropdown. Enter your email address. Click the orange 'Create Subscription' button below:

[image]

3. Deploy Lambda with the command: `sls deploy --stage dev` and the following code in `serverless.yml`:

```yaml
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-aws-alerts

# ... your function code, etc

custom:
  alerts:
    topics:
      alarm:
        topic: arn:aws:sns:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:myp-${sls:stage}-alerts
    alarms:
      - functionErrors
      - functionThrottles
      - functionInvocations
      - functionDuration
    nameTemplate: $[functionName]-$[metricName]-Alarm
    prefixTemplate: $[stackName]
```

That should get it working. You can trouble shoot by going over to your Cloudwatch Console. Click All Alarms:

[image]

You should be able to see that your alarms have been created here, like this:

[image]

The names follow the instruction in the above `serverless.yml` file: `nameTemplate: $[functionName]-$[metricName]-Alarm`
Click the alarm name and in the top right of the next screen click Actions>Edit:

[image]

You can see that the FunctionName refers to your Lambda function:
[image]

Scroll down and click the 'Next' button. You can see at the bottom of the Notifications section of the next screen which Topic the Alert is sending to:

[image]

It says 'myp-dev-alerts'. So we know that this matches the Topic I created.